# c++ Encapsulation questions

Tags: c++

I am trying to use std::sort with custom comparison function. For this, I have a class called `trySort`. This is the example code for the `trySort` class:

**trySort.h**

```
class trySort {

public:

private:
    std::string sortThis;
};
```

**trySort.cpp**

```
bool sortThisAsc (const trySort & rhs , const trySort & lhs) {
    return lhs.sortThis > rhs.sortThis;
}
```

this will throw an error if the member `sortThis` is private.

If I make `sortThis` a public member like this...

**trySort.h**

```
class trySort {

public:
      std::string sortThis;

private:           
};
```

**trySort.cpp**

```
bool sortThisAsc (const trySort & rhs , const trySort & lhs) {
    return lhs.sortThis > rhs.sortThis;
}
```

...It will work. It appears as though I make `sortThis` a public member.

So my question is: If I were to do this, am I not encapsulating my data?

If so, what are some other possible approachs other than putting it as a public member?

Comment: I would recommend against sorting by something in a class that is not publicly readable. I have a hard time coming up with examples of when it would actually make sense to hide the information, but allow the user to sort by it.

Comment: Why not make sortThisAsc a member of the class?

Comment: BTW: LHS and RHS mean "left hand side" and "right hand side", so it is clearer if you switch the parameters (and change the expression accordingly).

Comment: @AliAlamiri That's what I was getting at with my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `operator >` to `trySort` class.

```
trySort.h

class trySort {

public:
    bool operator >(trySort const &other) {
        return sortThis > other.sortThis;
    }  
private:
    std::string sortThis;
}
```

If you need more flexibility (some other kinds of comparisons), just encapsulate `sortThis` with a getter function.

```
trySort.h

class trySort {

public:
    std::string const &getSortThis() const {
        return sortThis;
    }

private:
    std::string sortThis;
}
```

If you are absolutely sure that `sortThis` will always be immutable through the course of a project, thus initialized in the constructor, you can leave it as a public const member, but in most cases this is very speculative approach.

```
trySort.h

class trySort {

public:
    trySort(std::string const sortThis)
        : sortThis(sortThis) {
    }

    const std::string sortThis;
}
```

Or you can do it with `friend`, but I would leave it as a last resort, since in most cases it turns out to represent excessive intimacy (there is always some other approach you can take to avoid using `friend`s). Using `friend` can be appropriate in some circumstances, but it never the less breaks encapsulation, with the difference that `friend` clause signals to class' clients that breakage was intentional.

Comment: ok I guess I will go with operator overloading method. thanks

Comment: it is `operator <` which is required for `std::sort`.

Comment: True, well noted. But the other `std::sort` signature works with `comp` function, which is `sortThisAsc` in this case. Main question was about encapsulation anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use friend :

```
class trySort {
friend bool sortThisAsc (const trySort & rhs , const trySort & lhs);

private:
       std::string sortThis;
}
```

It will give access only to this function and not to anything else

Comment: i guess your friend bool sortThisAsc (const trySort & rhs , const trySort & lhs); should be public? not private?

Comment: @user3175729 No, not really. Access specifiers do not apply to friends. They could be specified anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** This gets rid of the compilation error you mentioned, but only non-member functions can be passed to std::sort(), so this doesn't quite work.

In your cpp file, change the function definition from

```
bool sortThisAsc (const trySort & rhs , const trySort & lhs) {
```

to

```
bool trySort::sortThisAsc(const trySort & rhs, const trySort & lhs) {
```

Without the `trySort::` the function isn't defined in the `trySort` class scope (i.e. outside that class), so the compiler complains if you try to access private variables in `trySort`.

This way, you can keep it as a private method, as you originally asked for.

Comment: That will not work unless you have sortThisAsc declared in the header.

Comment: if I do it this way, I think I likely to get an error when I try to do sort(vector.begin(); vector.end() sortThisAsc)

Comment: I might be wrong, but wouldnt it be possible only if function is declared in the class as static.

Comment: No, actually we're both wrong. Only free, non-member functions will work.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two alternatives. 
Either you can declare a public getter to this data member as for example

```
class trySort {

public:
       const std::string & get_string() const { return sortThis; }

private:
       std::string sortThis;
}
```

and then in function sortThisAsc to write

```
bool sortThisAsc (const trySort & rhs , const trySort & lhs) {
    return lhs.get_string() > rhs.get_string();
}
```

Or you can declare the function as a friend function of the class

```
class trySort {

public:
       friend bool sortThisAsc (const trySort & rhs , const trySort & lhs);

private:
       std::string sortThis;
}
```

In this case the function definition will not be changed.